# Can I write OpenCL-C++ kernels for nVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: c++, opencl, opencl-c++

Over the past few years, the Khronos consortium has published versions of the OpenCL specification which include not just a [C-variant](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_C.html) OpenCL programming language, but a [C++-variant](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/2.2/html/OpenCL_Cxx.html) as well.

Is it possible to write such C++-like kernels targeting nVIDIA GPUs, using recent versions of CUDA and related tools? The NVIDIA [OpenCL samples](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) seem to be somewhat dated and C-only.

Comment: As far as I am aware NVIDIA stopped active development of OpenCL around OpenCL 1.2

Comment: @talonmies: Actually, nVIDIA started supporting OpenCL 2.0 [in 2017](https://streamhpc.com/blog/2017-02-22/nvidia-enables-opencl-2-0-beta-support/).

Answer (score 0):

With OpenCL 3.0 support you will be able to program kernels with "C++ for OpenCL" - It enables developers to use most C++17 features in OpenCL kernels. More information about OpenCL 3.0 is available [here](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/).

"NVIDIA will ship a conformant OpenCL 3.0 when the specification is finalized" - according to [this](https://www.khronos.org/news/press/khronos-group-releases-opencl-3.0) press release. The OpenCL 3.0 Finalized Specification was released on September 30th 2020. However as of February 2021, I'm not aware of any Nvidia drivers supporting OpenCL 3.0 yet.

Comment: Well, ok, but like you said - that's still pie-in-the-sky. Also, OpenCL 3.0 downgrades most capabilities/features from OpenCL 2.x back to OpenCL 1.x , doesn't it?

Comment: OpenCL 3.0 is already out on some platforms - Intel drivers already implement it. Nvidia is working on it so the supporting driver should be released soon. OpenCL 3.0 makes OpenCL 1.2 a baseline and OpenCL 2.x as optional features. It does not downgrade but offers flexibility to vendors.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't try Sycl? It uses OpenCL, by your C++-only host codes.

https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/48226/introduction-to-sycl/hello-world

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/sycl.hpp>

class vector_addition;

int main(int, char**) {
   cl::sycl::float4 a = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
   cl::sycl::float4 b = { 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 };
   cl::sycl::float4 c = { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

   cl::sycl::default_selector device_selector;

   cl::sycl::queue queue(device_selector);
   std::cout << "Running on "
             << queue.get_device().get_info<cl::sycl::info::device::name>()
             << "\n";
   {
      cl::sycl::buffer<cl::sycl::float4, 1> a_sycl(&a, cl::sycl::range<1>(1));
      cl::sycl::buffer<cl::sycl::float4, 1> b_sycl(&b, cl::sycl::range<1>(1));
      cl::sycl::buffer<cl::sycl::float4, 1> c_sycl(&c, cl::sycl::range<1>(1));
  
      queue.submit([&] (cl::sycl::handler& cgh) {
         auto a_acc = a_sycl.get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
         auto b_acc = b_sycl.get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);
         auto c_acc = c_sycl.get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::discard_write>(cgh);

         cgh.single_task<class vector_addition>([=] () {
         c_acc[0] = a_acc[0] + b_acc[0];
         });
      });
   }
   std::cout << "  A { " << a.x() << ", " << a.y() << ", " << a.z() << ", " << a.w() << " }\n"
        << "+ B { " << b.x() << ", " << b.y() << ", " << b.z() << ", " << b.w() << " }\n"
        << "------------------\n"
        << "= C { " << c.x() << ", " << c.y() << ", " << c.z() << ", " << c.w() << " }"
        << std::endl;
        
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I have an OpenCL-C++ kernel, can I stick it inside a SyCL lambda and have it work?

Comment: It may need adapter classes or extra conversion if types are not initially compatible. The link I put there is a live sycl runner, u can play on it. But Nvidia cuda debuggers or profilers may need more tweaking to use opencl profiling.